# how to find pulseaudio dbus server when using system-instance

Tags: dbus, pulseaudio

I'm trying to use org.PulseAudio1 and org.PulseAudio.ServerLookup1 to find the unix path to the pulseaudio dbus server exposed from module-dbus-protocol.

I'm enabling system mode via 'system-instance = yes'. I'm also enabling module-dbus-protocol. I've verified that both of these are enabled.

The trouble is that with 'system-instance = yes' there isn't a org.PulseAudio1 exposed on the system dbus bus, apparently due to this code in daemon/main.c:

```
if (!conf->system_instance) {
    if ((server_lookup = pa_dbusobj_server_lookup_new(c))) {
        if (!(lookup_service_bus = register_dbus_name(c, DBUS_BUS_SESSION, "org.PulseAudio1")))
            goto finish;
    }
}
```

How is one supposed to find the unix path to the dbus server when running as a system instance?

Comment: [This documentation page might be useful](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/Developer/Clients/DBus/ConnectingToServer/#lookupservicedetails).

Comment: I've looked but the rules seem relatively complex, require looking up the user id, building and checking file paths etc. Doesn't seem robust to me vs. a library call or always having a dbus interface available.